# get the list of db2 tables which have been changed since a particular timestamp say since 20120801185856 timestamp

Tags: db2, database-restore

Is there any way in IBM DB2 to get the list of tables which have been changed(updated/added/deleted) since a specific timestamp?

The problem i am facing is i have restored one backup on 25 July in one box from live db server and updated this restored DB while enabling features packs. Now the live DB server has changed since customer is accessing it and i cannot restore the latest backup as box1 have some addition tables/data.

So i wanted to know the list of tables which have been changed since last backup so that i can update those tables manually.
Please help.

Answer (score 5):

If you're on DB2 for Linux/Unix/Windows, this query should get what you need:

```
SELECT TRIM(TABSCHEMA) || '.' || TRIM(TABNAME),
       MAX(CREATE_TIME,ALTER_TIME)
FROM SYSCAT.TABLES
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

If you're on the mainframe, this one should do you:

```
SELECT RTRIM(CREATOR) || '.' || RTRIM(NAME),
       MAX(CREATEDTS,ALTEREDTS)
FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

However, neither of these will show deleted tables, as they're removed from the system catalog when they are dropped.

Comment: Query is not working properly. I tried updating a table manually and when i execute this query, It is not showing that table. I tried giving where ALTER_TIME > '2012-08-01' to filter the result nut it is showing the old date in ALTER_TIME column. My Query is 
SELECT TRIM(TABSCHEMA) || '.' || TRIM(TABNAME),
       CREATE_TIME,ALTER_TIME
FROM SYSCAT.TABLES
where TABNAME='STLOC'
ORDER BY 2 DESC
Please help.

Comment: This query is not fetching the required output if it was about table ROWS updated/inserted/deleted (not based on DML operation timestamps). I think the CREATE_TIME,ALTER_TIME colums correspond to DDL operations or stats collection. I have run and verified in db2 9.7 LUW.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest a delete trigger recording to a table the details at which a table's delete operation has taken place.