# List DB2 tables on which DML queries were performed recently

Tags: sql, database, db2

(This is similar but not a duplicate of [get the list of db2 tables which have been changed since a particular timestamp say since 20120801185856 timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775965/get-the-list-of-db2-tables-which-have-been-changed-since-a-particular-timestamp) )

I need to get a list of DB2 9.7 luw tables which are modified after a specific timestamp. Is there any sys tables which I can use? I came across the above question, and the query on SYSCAT.TABLES gives a list of tables created/altered with the timestamp. But I am looking for the  last insert/update/delete timestamp on each table.

Also LASTUSED column in SYSCAT.TABLES will not work for me as it is about last 'select'; I am looking for modifications and not select alone.

we have technical/metadata columns within the tables, but if there is a metadata table maintained by DB2 I would like to use that first.

Also this requirement is not for any change data log or audit trigger etc, I just want a list of tables inserted/updated/deleted after a specific timestamp.

Comment: I ended up with the below workaround to use the technical column LASTUPDATEDATE in whichever table this column is indexed. a)find list of tables with LASTUPDATEDATE indexed, b) do a count(*) with LASTUPDATEDATE  > the required date 

SELECT DISTINCT t.tabname
FROM syscat.tables t
 ,syscat.indexes i
WHERE i.TABNAME = t.TABNAME
 AND t.TABSCHEMA = i.TABSCHEMA
 AND t.TABSCHEMA = 'MYSCEMA'
 AND NOT (
  t.TABNAME LIKE '%_STAGE%'
  OR t.TABNAME LIKE '%_AUDIT%'
  )
 AND i.COLNAMES LIKE '%LASTUPDATEDATE%'

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is an Audit. That information is not in the catalog tables. Instead, you should activate the audit tool: db2audit, and then this tool will write the information that you want.

This can give you a lot of details about what is happening in the database. But, it impacts the performance.

This is a article about how to use this tool: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0603wasserman/

Remember, that the data is not logged as part of the utility, because this is against the privacy. Thus, you cannot know what exactly a user modified in the database. With db2audit, you can know which action was performed on which object.

If you really want to know what a user did, then you need to develop your own tracking system. You can implement something with triggers or use a logging utility like log4db2 in stored procedures.

Comment: Thanks, but my requirements are minimal, just a list of tables, not really in the detailed audit level